# UIPageControl does not respond to touch, does not change dot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios4

I have a UIPageControl. When I click on a dot to change the page, nothing happens. Second dot does not get highlighted.

It works fine, however, when I scroll my UIScrollView. In that case the second dot is highlighted.

```
pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init] ;
pageControl.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 430.0f);
pageControl.numberOfPages=nPages;
pageControl.currentPage=0;
pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = YES;
pageControl.userInteractionEnabled =YES;

[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageTurn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
```

This should be called when I change pageControl Value but it does not get called since it does not respond to touch.

```
- (void) pageTurn: (UIPageControl *) aPageControl
{
    int whichPage = aPageControl.currentPage;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    sv.contentOffset = CGPointMake(320.0f * whichPage, 0.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the pagecontrol's frame (width and height) not just the center otherwise it has zero dimensions and does not respond to touches.

```
pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] 
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 430, 200, 50)];
pageControl.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 430.0f);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I set number of pages to 7. When i clicked on dots 2 and 3, it didn't respond. I clicked on dot 4 and it responded and kept on clicking it until i reached last dot i.e. 7. Now when i click on dot 2 and 3, it responds !!

Comment: @pratikshabhisikar: The answer was specifically to solve Alex L's problem.  Of course it's not and can't be the answer to every UIPageControl problem.  If it doesn't happen to solve your specific situation, the cause of and solution to your problem must be different and does not justify a downvote.

Comment: I was doing [[UIPageControl alloc] init] without setting a frame because I always tend to think that the UIPageControl sizes to fit automatically. And I was wrong!

[[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect] made the trick. TY!

Comment: Also, make sure userInteractionEnabled is set to true

Answer (score 4):

I had the same symptoms in my app recently. My solution was to move the `UIPageControl` up in the view hierarchy (z-index, if you will) so that it was above the `UIScrollView` inside the root view.  If it is not above the `UIScrollView` it will not get touches even though it looks like it is visible.

I am not sure whether this is your problem, but just thought I would chime in.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it helps to bring the pageControl to front of all overlapping subviews.

That was the Trick in my case:

```
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront: pageControl];
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when the pagecontrol width is too small this can also happen. Try to set width of pagecontrol component to be fairly large,e.g. 320. Then it should work better.

Comment: your comment "Wake me" and I set the pageControl to the width of his parent view, and now the repsond to taps are great.

Comment: Good! I am happy to know that.